# Preparing for Zend Framework 2 (namespacing controllers)

Tags: php, zend-framework, namespaces, zend-framework2

With a stable version of Zend Framework 2 on the horizon, we have been slowly implementing some ZF2 components, changing conventions, implementing namespaces, etc.  It would be nice to have all of our controllers namespaced prior to the move, just to simply things, but I haven't found a good way to accomplish that goal.

Does anyone have any suggestions on controller namespacing in ZF1?  I don't mind editing the ZF1 library files at this point.

```php
namespace Product;

use Zend_Controller_Action as AbstractActionController;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{}
```

Comment: Does the ZF1 autoloader support autoloading namespaced files? If so then just shift your controllers to namespaced names and everything should still work. I'm not sure if it autoloads namespaced classes though.

Comment: Just for the record, the correct namespace for ZF2 Controllers would be `Module\Controllers`

Comment: ZF2 skeleton app uses Application\Controller\IndexController ([module name]/Controller/[controller name]Controller).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a while, but I found that this can be done with a custom dispatcher:

```php
<?php

namespace Webjawns\Controller\Dispatcher;

use Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard as Dispatcher;

class Standard extends Dispatcher
{
    /**
     * Format action class name
     *
     * @param string $moduleName Name of the current module
     * @param string $className Name of the action class
     * @return string Formatted class name
     */
    public function formatClassName($moduleName, $className)
    {
        return $this->formatModuleName($moduleName) . '\Controller\\' . $className;
    }

    /**
     * Convert a class name to a filename
     *
     * @param string $class
     * @return string
     */
    public function classToFilename($class)
    {
        return str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class) . '.php';
    }
}
```

Then somewhere in the entry point to the application:

```php
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->setDispatcher(
    new \Webjawns\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard());
```